# Recursive / fan-out in Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I'm attempting to piece together a Rx pipeline that works as follows:

1. I have written a function that takes in an IObservable providing me with profiles containing information about a company
2. I query a variety of data sources to find potentially related company profiles, all in parallel. I merge that into a single IObservable of company profiles.
3. When I get back these potentially related profiles, I compare them to profiles that I have already observed and, if they have a relevance > 80% and are not the same as any profiles I've already observed, I consider them a match.
4. I want to feed the matching companies back into step 1 so that I can search for related data to these new matching profiles.

I bootstrap the process with some known good profiles.

Eventually, there's no more matching profiles that haven't already been seen, and so the process ends.

I'm having trouble programming this. If I use a Subject to allow the tail end of the pipeline to send its profiles to the beginning of the workflow, then no one is going to call OnCompleted and I never find out that the process has ended. If I develop this with recursion instead, I seem to always end up with a stack overflow since I'm trying to call a function with its own return value.

Can anyone help me with how I can accomplish this task in a way where I can determine that the process has ended?

Comment: If I were to use hardware terminology, are you looking for a multiplexer-demultiplexer?

Comment: @JerKimball I'm not sure what you mean by that in this context.

Comment: Hmm...let me try rephrasing: You have multiple sources, which you want to mangle into a single stream, and then "unmangle" occurrences from that single stream back to the corresponding multiple stream side?

Comment: @JerKimball No, I don't need to "unmerge" the merged stream. I need to feed the merged stream back into the beginning of the Rx workflow that generated it. Its a recursive process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you want a dataflow like this:

```
seed profiles --> source --> get related --> output
                     ^                    |
                     |                    v
                     -<--- transform <-----
```

This seems like a case where solving the general problem is as easy or easier than the specific one, so I'll propose a generic "feedback" function that should give you the building blocks you need:

*edit: fixed function to complete*

```
IObservable<TResult> Feedback<T, TResult>(this IObservable<T> seed,
                                          Func<T, IObservable<TResult>> produce,
                                          Func<TResult, IObservable<T>> feed)
    {
        return Observable.Create<TResult>(
                obs =>
                {
                    var ret = new CompositeDisposable();
                    Action<IDisposable> partComplete = 
                        d =>
                        {
                            ret.Remove(d);
                            if (ret.Count == 0) obs.OnCompleted();
                        };
                    Action<IObservable<T>, Action<T>> ssub =
                        (o, n) =>
                        {
                            var disp = new SingleAssignmentDisposable();
                            ret.Add(disp);
                            disp.Disposable = o.Subscribe(n, obs.OnError, () => partComplete(disp));
                        };
                    Action<IObservable<TResult>, Action<TResult>> rsub =
                        (o, n) =>
                        {
                            var disp = new SingleAssignmentDisposable();
                            ret.Add(disp);
                            disp.Disposable = o.Subscribe(n, obs.OnError, () => partComplete(disp));
                        };

                    Action<T> recurse = null;
                    recurse = s =>
                              {
                                  rsub(produce(s),
                                       r => 
                                       {
                                           obs.OnNext(r);
                                           ssub(feed(r), recurse);
                                       });
                              };

                    ssub(seed, recurse);
                    return ret;
                });
    }
```

In your case, `T` and `TResult` appear to be the same, so `feed` will be the identity function.  `produce` will be the functions used to implement step 2 and 3.

Some sample code I tested this function with:

```
void Main()
{
    var seed = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    var found = new HashSet<int>();
    var mults = seed.ToObservable()
                    .Feedback(i =>
                              {
                                  return Observable.Range(0, 5)
                                         .Select(r => r * i)
                                         .TakeWhile(v => v < 100)
                                         .Where(v => found.Add(v));
                              },
                              i => Observable.Return(i));

    using (var disp = mults.Dump())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static IDisposable Dump<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
{
    return source.Subscribe(item => Console.WriteLine(item),
                            ex => Console.WriteLine("Error occurred in dump observable: " + ex.ToString()),
                            () => Console.WriteLine("Dump completed"));
}
```

Comment: This is extremely close, BUT, I also need to know when the process "stops." Since each time I recurse I filter and send back fewer results than I received, eventually the process has 0 items sent back to the beginning step and the process completes. I need to be able to detect this without using an arbitrary timeout.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer I didn't even think about completing.  The problem with the original version is of course that the forward and backwards observables are each waiting for the other to complete before they complete.  I've edited to include another version that tracks outstanding observables and completes when none are left.  Pending thorough testing, there is a chance a race condition may exist, but my basic test still works.

Comment: Even closer! My last remaining issue is because there is no established pipeline, but rather a function is being recursively called, I can't use stateful operators. For example, that "transform" step in your diagram cannot meaningfully include a `Distinct`, since it will only perform the operation on a single batch of results instead of the entire process.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer The example program shows one way to do that.  I'm not sure how general it is, but you could potentially wrap the set management into a function like `Func<T, IObservable<R>> DistinctForAll<T, R>(Func<T, IObservable<R>> selector)`.