# Create stable feedback loop in Logic Gate Simulator using Reactive Extensions?

Tags: c#, recursion, system.reactive

I have created a very simple logic gate simulator which can take IEnumerable feeds on the input side and flow through a series of gates producing High/Low Bits accurately on the output side.

The idea is to extend the concept to a multi-gate network feeding values stored in arrays in an in-memory database to the inputs of the network and to replicate a scenario evaluation ruleset in the logic gate network. The hypothesis is that the streaming action allowed by Rx should provide a mechanism to evaluate 400,000 scenarios in a timely manner which avoids searching and array iteration. The majority of the inputs are feed forward only but there are some which need to work with the output from the network as the decision for the next scenario relies on the output from the previous scenario.

Everything works fine until I try to create a feedback loop in the network attempting to use the network's output stream as an input stream to a gate whose output is part of the resolution of the network's output.

I'd like to know how I can take the output stream and use it in this fashion. I did have a look at ["Recursive / fan-out in Reactive Extensions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297977/recursive-fan-out-in-reactive-extensions) which feels like it might help but I am very new to Rx and didn't fully understand it.

Here is the code I have so far..very simple, a bit messy (apologies) and currently broken (although will work if feedback attempt is removed and replaced with a feed forward one).

```cs
        class Program
        {
            private static AndGate _andGate;
            private static XorGate _xorGate;

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var data = new List<decimal>();
                var data2 = new List<decimal>();

                var output = new List<Tuple<Bit, Bit, Bit>>();

                var rnd = new Random();

                //for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                //{
                //    data.Add(rnd.Next(0, 100));
                //    data2.Add(rnd.Next(0, 100));
                //}
                data.Add(10);
                data.Add(30);
                data.Add(80);
                data.Add(5);
                data.Add(34);
                data.Add(27); 



                data2.Add(10);
                data2.Add(5);
                data2.Add(10);
                data2.Add(34);
                data2.Add(67);
                data2.Add(80);



                var stream = data.ToObservable();
                var stream2 = data2.ToObservable();

                var filter = new DataFilter(stream, a => a > 27);
                var filter2 = new DataFilter(stream2, a => a < 12);

                _andGate = new AndGate {InputA = filter.OutputStream};

                _andGate.InputB = new XorGate(filter2.OutputStream, _andGate.Output.Publish()).Output;

                _andGate.SetOutput();


                //filter.OutputStream.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
                //filter2.OutputStream.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
                _andGate.Output.Subscribe(x=>Console.WriteLine(x));

                //var zippedSequence =
                //    Observable.When(
                //        filter.OutputStream.And(filter2.OutputStream)
                //              .Then((first, second) => new [] { first, second }));


                //zippedSequence.Subscribe(x=>Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", x[0], x[1]));

                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }

        public class DataFilter
        {
            protected IObservable<Bit> ValueStream;

            public IObservable<Bit> OutputStream
            {
                get { return ValueStream; }
            }

            public DataFilter(IObservable<decimal> stream, Func<decimal, bool> operation )
            {
                ValueStream = stream.Select(a => operation(a)? Bit.High : Bit.Low);
            }

        }

        public class AndGate
        {
            protected IObservable<Bit> StreamA; 
            protected IObservable<Bit> StreamB;
            protected IObservable<Bit> OutputStream;

            public IObservable<Bit> InputA { get { return StreamA; } set { StreamA = value; } }
            public IObservable<Bit> InputB { get { return StreamB; } set { StreamB = value; } }

            public IObservable<Bit> Output
            {
                get { return OutputStream; }
            }

            public AndGate()
            {
                OutputStream = Observable.When(StreamA.And(StreamB).Then(Determine));
            }

            public AndGate(IObservable<Bit> streamA, IObservable<Bit> streamB)
            {
                OutputStream = Observable.When(streamA.And(streamB).Then(Determine));
            }

            private Bit Determine(Bit bitA, Bit bitB)
            {
                return bitA == Bit.High && bitB == Bit.High ? Bit.High : Bit.Low;
            }
        }

        public class OrGate
        {
            protected IObservable<Bit> InputStreamA;
            protected IObservable<Bit> InputStreamB;
            protected IObservable<Bit> OutputStream;

            public IObservable<Bit> Output
            {
                get { return OutputStream; }
            }

            public OrGate()
            {

            }

            public OrGate(IObservable<Bit> streamA, IObservable<Bit> streamB)
            {
                OutputStream = Observable.When(streamA.And(streamB).Then(Determine));
            }

            private Bit Determine(Bit bitA, Bit bitB)
            {
                return bitA == Bit.High || bitB == Bit.High ? Bit.High : Bit.Low;
            }
        }

        public class XorGate
        {
            protected IObservable<Bit> StreamA;
            protected IObservable<Bit> StreamB;
            protected IObservable<Bit> OutputStream;

            public IObservable<Bit> Output
            {
                get { return OutputStream; }
            }

            public XorGate(IObservable<Bit> streamA, IObservable<Bit> streamB)
            {
                OutputStream = Observable.When(streamA.And(streamB).Then(Determine));
            }

            private Bit Determine(Bit bitA, Bit bitB)
            {
                return bitA == Bit.High ^ bitB == Bit.High ? Bit.High : Bit.Low;
            }
        }

        public enum Bit { Low = 0, High = 1}
```

Edit:
I added this diagram to aid understanding. The line in red is the one causing problems. ;-)

[image: Simple Logic diagram]

Another EDIT:
I have continued to whittle away at this little problem and discovered the Generate and Publish/Connect elements of Rx which have enabled this problem to be solved. By publishing the output of the gate network it becomes possible to examine the output and set changes in elements of the network based on the output value. The Generate method allows me to set up a xor gate with two internal bit streams, 1 High and  1 Low (initially), the output being High from this arrangement. The xor gate has a status bit which can be set from outside the gate using the published output stream. This method latches the output of the xor gate High or Low.

```
        class Program
        {
            private static AndGate _andGate1;
            private static AndGate _andGate2;
            private static XorGate _xorGate;

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var data = new List<decimal>();
                var data2 = new List<decimal>();

                var output = new List<Tuple<Bit, Bit, Bit>>();

                var rnd = new Random();

                //for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                //{
                //    data.Add(rnd.Next(0, 100));
                //    data2.Add(rnd.Next(0, 100));
                //}

                data.Add(10);
                data.Add(23);
                data.Add(80);
                data.Add(5);
                data.Add(34);
                data.Add(27); 

                data2.Add(10);
                data2.Add(5);
                data2.Add(10);
                data2.Add(34);
                data2.Add(67);
                data2.Add(80);

                //Raw Data streams
                var stream = data.ToObservable();
                var stream2 = data2.ToObservable();

                //Converted to Bit streams
                var filter = new DataFilter(stream, a => a > 27);
                var filter2 = new DataFilter(stream2, a => a < 12);

                //Gate network
                _xorGate = new XorGate();
                _andGate1 = new AndGate(filter.OutputStream, _xorGate.Output);
                _andGate2 = new AndGate(_andGate1.Output, filter2.OutputStream );

                //Publish and Connect to the outcome of the network
                var observable = _andGate2.Output.SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default).Publish();
                observable.Connect();

                //Subscribe to the outcome to allow changes to be made to the XorGate
                observable.Subscribe(x => { if (x == Bit.High) { _xorGate.SetStatusBitHigh(x); } });

                //View the results
                observable.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }

        public class DataFilter
        {
            protected IObservable<Bit> ValueStream;

            public IObservable<Bit> OutputStream
            {
                get { return ValueStream; }
            }

            public DataFilter(IObservable<decimal> stream, Func<decimal, bool> operation )
            {
                ValueStream = stream.Select(a => operation(a)? Bit.High : Bit.Low);
            }

        }

        public class AndGate
        {
            protected IObservable<Bit> OutputStream;

            public IObservable<Bit> Output
            {
                get { return OutputStream; }
            }


            public AndGate(IObservable<Bit> streamA, IObservable<Bit> streamB)
            {
                OutputStream = Observable.When(streamA.And(streamB).Then(Determine));
            }

            private Bit Determine(Bit bitA, Bit bitB)
            {
                return bitA == Bit.High && bitB == Bit.High ? Bit.High : Bit.Low;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is really a bastardized XorGate as I force two Bit streams into the inputs
        /// Keep one High, start the other Low and then send it High when a high signal results from the output of the network
        /// This allows me to force the network output low i.e. take no action...
        /// ...until the Bit is sent low again by another network (no done yet)
        /// </summary>
        public class XorGate
        {
            protected IObservable<Bit> StreamA;
            protected IObservable<Bit> StreamB;
            protected IObservable<Bit> OutputStream;

            protected Bit StatusBit;

            public void SetStatusBitHigh(Bit input)
            {
                //No action if circumstances are as you want them
                if (input == StatusBit) return;

                //Belt and Braces check here
                if (StatusBit == Bit.Low && input == Bit.High)
                {
                    StatusBit = Bit.High;
                }

            }

            public void SetStatusBitLow(Bit input)
            {
                //No action if circumstances are as you want them
                if (input == StatusBit) return;

                //Belt and Braces check here
                if (StatusBit == Bit.High && input == Bit.Low)
                {
                    StatusBit = Bit.Low;
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Output the stream safely
            /// </summary>
            public IObservable<Bit> Output
            {
                get { return OutputStream; }
            }


            public XorGate()
            {
                //Set the StatusBit to Low initially
                StatusBit = Bit.Low;

                //Create a permanent high stream for one of the (imaginary) gate pins
                var streamA = Observable.Generate(Bit.High, bit => true, bit => bit, bit => bit);

                //Create a low stream for the other (imaginary) pin
                //One which sets itself to the value of the StatusBit so that a StatusBit = Bit.High will produce a High stream
                var streamB = Observable.Generate(Bit.Low, bit => true, bit => StatusBit, bit => bit);

                //Produce the output
                OutputStream = Observable.When(streamA.And(streamB).Then(Determine));
            }

            private Bit Determine(Bit bitA, Bit bitB)
            {
                return bitA == Bit.High ^ bitB == Bit.High ? Bit.High : Bit.Low;
            }
        }

        public class OrGate
        {
            protected IObservable<Bit> OutputStream;

            public IObservable<Bit> Output
            {
                get { return OutputStream; }
            }

            public OrGate(IObservable<Bit> streamA, IObservable<Bit> streamB)
            {
                OutputStream = Observable.When(streamA.And(streamB).Then(Determine));
            }

            private Bit Determine(Bit bitA, Bit bitB)
            {
                return bitA == Bit.High || bitB == Bit.High ? Bit.High : Bit.Low;
            }
        }

        public enum Bit { Low = 0, High = 1}
```

Circuit now Looks like this

[image: Modified Circuit]

I would welcome comments corrections and suggestions to achieve this in other and better ways as it still feels a bit hacky to me.

Comment: There is a way of writing real-world feedback systems using Rx. But it needs to work in discrete time and in your model there is no notion of time. The movement of data (voltage) should be separated from the passage of time.

Comment: @Asti. I had a brief discussion around that concept this morning with my business partner basically coming to the conclusion that the inability to make feedback work was a result of timing issues. We were kicking around the idea of creating a simulated clock pulse to manage when things happened but it was a case of the blind leading the blind as we are no sufficiently conversant in Rx. Would you or anyone else in the Rx community have any points to flesh out the time aspect of Rx feedback loops?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to defer the output of the system to the input after. This is the key bit in a simulated computed feedback system.

```
    public delegate IObservable<T> Feedback<T>(IObservable<T> feedback, out IObservable<T> output);
    public static IObservable<T> FeedbackSystem<T>(Feedback<T> closure)
    {
        IObservable<T> source = Observable.Empty<T>(), output;
        source = closure(Observable.Defer(() => source), out output);
        return output;
    }
```

Here is an example system for a speed governer which stabilises the speed at 100, even though there are fluctuations.
It adjusts the acceleration based on feedback from the speed at which system is running.
If you are not familiar with the laws of motion, basically speed is a result of acceleration, and acceleration is controlled by the speed feedback.

```
        var system =
        FeedbackSystem((IObservable<double> acceleration, out IObservable<double> velocity) =>
        {
            //Time axis: moves forward every 0.1s
            double t = 0.1; var timeaxis = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(t));

            velocity = acceleration.Sample(timeaxis)                //move in time
                                   .Scan((u, a) => u + a * t)   //u' = u + at
                                   .Select(u => u + new Random().Next(10))  //some variations in speed
                                   .Publish().RefCount();                   //avoid recalculation

            //negative feedback
            var feedback = velocity.Select(u => 0.5 * (100 - u));

            return feedback.Select(a => Math.Min(a, 15.0))  //new limited acceleration
                           .StartWith(0);                   //initial value          
        });

        system.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

The feedback gets computed over a time-step. Even logic gates gave switching time.