# What's the idiomatic way of doing recursive network calls in ReactiveX world?

Tags: rx-java, system.reactive

I have an endpoint that returns results for a specified date. If the response has enough data, I'd like to return that data. If there weren't enough items, another call should be made with a changed date to get more results. Aggregate the data until there is enough items or a certain maximum number of calls has been reached and return that data.

Currently I've created a solution that uses a Subject, which works, but feels like a hack. I was wondering if there's a more idiomatic way of performing this task while staying in the Observable pipeline?

**Update (January 7, 2016):**

The following SO post has been instrumental in figuring out the solution for my problem:

[Recursive / fan-out in Reactive Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297977/recursive-fan-out-in-reactive-extensions?rq=1)

My solution closely resembles the one in that post. If anyone is still interested in my solution, make a comment and I'll post it.

Comment: You should show your current solution in your question. Then we have something concrete to work from.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is one of the possible solutions.

Basically, you take a stream of integers and modify it to make an api call. `concatMap` is used to make api calls sequential.

```
Observable.range(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        .concatMap(i-> apiCall())
        .takeUntil(data-> someCondition)
        .toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know your specific problem, one possible solution could be to use `merge()` that calls the method recursively such as,

```
    Observable<Result> getData(Date input, int count, int maximum)
    {       
        Observable<Result> res = getResults(input);
        int cnt = res.count().toBlocking().single();
        cnt += count;
        if(cnt < maximum){
            return Observable.merge(res, getData(newDate(input), cnt, maximum));
        }
        return res; 
    }
```

Use `getData(input, 0, max)` to call it by giving an initial count 0. Don't know if it satisfies your needs.
It is also common to use `flatMap()` for recursive calls.